# Error while consuming WCF service in Windows Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-services

I have added wcf service in "Windows Service" as service reference. but when i try to create instance it simply gives me following error

> "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IClientService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element."

**Code**

```
            pushNotification push_notification = new pushNotification();
            var proxy = new ServiceReference1.ClientServiceClient();

            using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel))
            {
                // Add a HTTP Header to an outgoing request

                HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                requestMessage.Headers["Authorization"] = "Push Notification";
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;
                push_notification = proxy.GetPendingNotification();
            }
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:4567/ClientService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IClientService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"    behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" />
  </client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Well, have you setup a matching endpoint in your `app.config` file?

Comment: No. not really. i assume it should automatically pick that up as i have added it as reference.

Comment: can you please show your config file's `ServiceModel` section..

Comment: i have added binding and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you put the endpoint information in your main App.config or Web.config.
If you've added the service reference in a separate project you need to copy the config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:4567/ClientService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IClientService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In your startup project `App.config`/`Web.config`!

Comment: i am getting this error however i have added endpoints in app.config "There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:4567/ClientService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

Comment: It looks like your local WCF service is stopped. If you have another project with the service you need to keep it running while you run the client

Comment: I get the above error on this line " push_notification = proxy.GetPendingNotification();"

Comment: sorry the error is "Manual addressing is enabled on this factory, so all messages sent must be pre-addressed."

Comment: i google it and it says it is because this is no service behavior added. i added the behavior and i get this error "Operation 'isServiceInstalled' of contract 'IClientService' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped."                                  on this line  using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel))